# Use DI Nodeset instead of Standard Nodeset http://opcfoundation.org/UA/

Tags: opc-ua, open62541, nodesets

I working with Open62541-Lib. When i Creat Objects with UA_Server_addObjectNode() or UA_Server_addVariableNode() they always get Namespace 0 and belongs to http://opcfoundation.org/UA/. Can i define another Namespace in the Code, so every created Node refers to the DI Nodeset?
I used NodesetCompiler, its create a .c and .h data as Schema from DI-Nodeset and i only can load them as empty Nodes.